# JavaScript: Developing a search query for MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, electron

I need some assistance developing a search query to give a button in my Electron application some functionality.

This is how far I have gotten:

```
module.exports = (criteria, sortProperty, offset = 0, limit = 20) => {
  // write a query that will follow sort, offset, limit options only
  // do not worry about criteria yet
  Artist.sort()
    .find()
    .offset()
    .limit();
};
```

I am skipping `criteria` for now so feel free to ignore that. The user should be able to sort by artist name, age and albums released. The `sortProperty` will go in ascending fashion so I know I need to sort with a value of `1`.

The real challenge behind the sorting is that I need to specify different `sortProperties` but only one at any given time.

I want to be able to pass in a different `sortProperty` depending on what the user has selected. I would like to have a key that is whatever the `sortProperty` is.

So if `sortProperty` is equal to age, I need to ensure I have a statement that says age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you already have all the required parts to do the query. You just need to create the `sort` selector based on your `sortProperty`. This will be an object with a key equal to the value held by `sortProperty` for example `age`. The result will look like this

```
module.exports = (criteria, sortProperty, offset = 0, limit = 20) => {
  return Artist
    .find()
    .sort({ [sortProperty]: 1 })
    .skip(offset)
    .limit(limit);
};
```

## Note

To illustrate the dynamic key assignation, here's a snippet

```js
const sortProperty = 'age';
const selector = { [sortProperty]: 1 };

console.log(selector);
```

Comment: Thank you again for this answer. I studied your answer for a few days because I always want to know what is going on and not just the answer and I will be adding kind of an addendum to your answer as an answer. The thought process helped me and hopefully will help others in the future who come upon this post.

Answer (score 0):

So the above answer is the best solution as it is ES6 and more elegant. I wanted to share the ES5 old school way that I learned after I got this answer and studied it more in-depth.

In the ES5 way I learned that you can define an object like so:

```
module.exports = (criteria, sortProperty, offset = 0, limit = 20) => {
  // write a query that will follow sort, offset, limit options only
  // do not worry about criteria yet
  const sortOrder = {};

  Artist.find({})
    .sort()
    .skip(offset)
    .limit(limit);
};
```

I made it an empty object and then look at it and add `sortProperty` equals `1` like so:

```
module.exports = (criteria, sortProperty, offset = 0, limit = 20) => {
  // write a query that will follow sort, offset, limit options only
  // do not worry about criteria yet
  const sortOrder = {};
  sortOrder[sortProperty] = 1;

  Artist.find({})
    .sort()
    .skip(offset)
    .limit(limit);
};
```

And then I can pass in the `sortOrder` like so:

```
module.exports = (criteria, sortProperty, offset = 0, limit = 20) => {
  // write a query that will follow sort, offset, limit options only
  // do not worry about criteria yet
  const sortOrder = {};
  sortOrder[sortProperty] = 1;

  Artist.find({})
    .sort(sortOrder)
    .skip(offset)
    .limit(limit);
};
```

Okay, so that is the ES5 approach if anyone was interested in learning about it, but as you can see above the ES6 solution looks better.

The whole problem with creating an object and simultaneously adding a property to it is that its not well supported in ES5, we have to first declare an object, then add a property to it and set that property equal to 1.

The square brackets mean look at the `sortProperty` variable:

```
sortOrder[sortProperty] = 1;
```

which is a string and I am trying to add on a `sortOrder` property of `name` to this object and set it equal to `1` and so the end result if you ran this in a Chrome console or in code snippet is `{ name: 1 }`.

The learning curve for me and what the selected answer helped me learn was ES6 interpolated properties or keys. This thing:

```
.sort({ [sortProperty]: 1 })
```

What is happening here is at runtime look at the `sortProperty` variable and whatever its equal to, add that property to this object and give it a value of `1`.

So to be clear, yes the original answer given was the elegant solution I went with:

```
module.exports = (criteria, sortProperty, offset = 0, limit = 20) => {
  // write a query that will follow sort, offset, limit options only
  // do not worry about criteria yet
  Artist.find()
    .sort({ [sortProperty]: 1 })
    .skip(offset)
    .limit(limit);
};
```

I was just sharing what I learned along the way in studying and implementing it.